# Main Program and Shared Library initializes same static variable in __static_initialization_and_destruction_0

Tags: shared-libraries, segmentation-fault, symbols, static-variables, dlopen

Does anyone know why a library initialized within dlopen() would initialize a static variable owned by the main program.  Both the main program and shared library have a copy of the static variable, but for some reason the shared library re-initializes the main program's copy of the static variable and destructs it, causing a segfault when the main program attempts to destruct it.

Is this a case of bad name mangling in the symbol table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a case where the runtime linker only wants a single active copy of a symbol in a process.  If both a shared object and the executable have a copy of the symbol, the runtime linker will resolve all references to one of those.

What you can do to solve this problem is to use symbol reduction using the [version command](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.20/ld/VERSION.html#VERSION) of the link editor when building the shared object.  Make sure the symbol for the static variable is not global and you will get the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: Hrm, I seem to be having a problem implementing the version script and passing it to the linker. It is complaining about a syntax error. Here is the script file I used: "{ global: local: *; }" Any ideas? I looked for examples but they all seem to fail the syntax check.  Or is it better to put the __asm__ directive directly in the source?

Comment: @Paul - my scripts look like `VERSION { { global: ...; local *; }; }` and then I just use the filename of that file on linker command line.

Comment: @Samuel - Thanks a bunch, after getting the version script completed and adding a couple of symbols to the global context it now works!

Comment: @samuel : Wow I din't know that! I have a similar problem. Do you know how the dynamic linker choose one sympbol over another ? Or any good link about it ? Thanks.

Comment: I do not get it. How can there be two copies of a same variable? What variable is instantiated twice, once in the main executable and once in the SO?