# Why the main executable and a shared library loaded by dlopen share one copy of a namespace static variable?

Tags: c++, static, linker, shared-libraries, dlopen

As far as I understand namespace scope static variables should have one copy in each compilation unit. So if I have a header file like this:

```
class BadLad {                                                                                      
public:                                                                                             
    BadLad();                                                                                       
    ~BadLad();                                                                                      
};                                                                                                  

static std::unique_ptr<int> sCount;                                                                 
static BadLad sBadLad;
```

and badlad.cpp

```
#include "badlad.h"

BadLad::BadLad() {
    if (!sCount) {
        sCount.reset(new int(1));
        std::cout<<"BadLad, reset count, "<<*sCount<<std::endl;
    }
    else {
        ++*sCount;
        std::cout<<"BadLad, "<<*sCount<<std::endl;
    }
}

BadLad::~BadLad() {
    if (sCount && --*sCount == 0) {
        std::cout<<"~BadLad, delete "<<*sCount<<std::endl;
        delete(sCount.release());
    }
    else {
        std::cout<<"~BadLad, "<<*sCount<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

I expect sCount and sBadLad to be unique in each cpp file that includes badlad.h.

However, I found it's not the case in the following experiment:

- I compile badlad to a shared library `libBadLad.so`.
- I create another shared library `libPlugin.so` which links
  `libBadLad.so`, only plugin.cpp includes `badlad.h`, so I expect
  there is one copy of `sCount` in libPlugin.so.
- I create a main program that links libBadLad.so, I expect there is
  one copy of `sCount` in main.

The main program looks like this:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main() {
    void* dll1 = dlopen("./libplugin.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    dlclose(dll1);

    void* dll2 = dlopen("./libplugin.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    dlclose(dll2);

    return 0;
}
```

When executing the main program, I can see the `sCount` variable is first created and set to 1 before main is called, which is expected. But then after the first `dlopen` is called, `sCount` is incremented to 2, and subsequently decreased to 1 when `dlclose` is called. The same happens to the second dlopen/dlclose.

So my questions is, why there is only one copy of sCount? Why the linker doesn't keep the copies separate (which I think is what most people expect)? It behaves the same if I link libPlugin.so to main directly instead of dlopen.

I'm running this on macOS with clang-4 (clang-900.0.39.2).

EDIT: please see the full source code in [this repo](https://github.com/wangshan/sketch/tree/master/load_shared_lib_with_static).

Comment: You could take a thorough look at the [2nd post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624880/static-class-variables-in-dynamic-library-and-main-program?rq=1) in the related section. I think the underlying mechanism is merely the same.

Comment: welcome to dll hell. Basically each dll will have the static/global variables  liked with it's code alone.

Comment: @TheDude that post says there are indeed two copies, but the main one somehow masked the one from shared library? but why the linker prefers to do this, doesn't it go against common understanding of static variable?

Comment: I believe it's a _thread safety_ thing, because shared libraries can be hosted in different thread contexts, and static variable instantiation is guaranteed to be thread safe. The linker doesn't know anything about the thread context though. I'm not sure about that, otherwise I'd post it as an answer. [`dlopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html) is a POSIX standard BTW.

Comment: One idea that comes to mind, which could work the way you expect to have separate copies for separate translation units, is to put the `static` variable definitions into an anonymous namespace in those TUs. These should be really private copies within there.

Comment: @TheDude I tried that, by putting sCount and sBadLad in a `namespace {}`, but it doesn't work either, there is still one copy. The other post you linked suggested to use version script, I haven't tried it but it feels wrong, it means my build script will need to know my library's implementation details.

Comment: If your main program links libBadLad.so, then there's only one copy of libBadLad.so during the execution. libPlugin.so doesn't load its own copy.

Comment: Is that because the symbols have already been resolved at start up time? Then why is BadLad constructor called after dlopen?

Comment: It isn't on Linux or on Windows/Cygwin. Show your build commands, print the address of the object being constructed/destructed (just `<< this`), and show your output.

Comment: Your executable uses three (two at a time) different instances of sBadLad, but only one instance of sCount. Why is that is an interesting question that I don't have time to answer right now, maybe later.

Comment: I have scribbled a new answer that seems to describe your situation adequately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Iteration 2)

What happens in your case is very interesting and very unfortunate. Let's analyze it step by step.

1. Your program is linked against `libBadLad.so`. This shared library is thus loaded on program startup. Constructors of static objects are executed before `main`.
2. Your program then dlopens `libplugin.so`. This shared library is then loaded, and constructors of static objects are executed.
3. What about `libBadLad.so` that `libplugin.so` is linked against? Since the process already contains an image of `libBadLad.so`, **this shared library is not loaded the second time**. `libplugin.so` could just as well not link against it at all.
4. Back to the static objects of `libplugin.so`. There are two of them, `sCount` and `sBadLad`. *Both are constructed, in order*.
5. `sBadLad` has a user-defined non-inline constructor. *It is not defined in `libplugin.so`*, so it is resolved against the already-loaded `libBadLad.so`, which has this symbol defined.
6. `BadLad::BadLad` *from `libBadLad.so`* is called.
7. This constructor references a static variable `sCount`. *This resolves to `sCount` from `libBadLad.so`, not `sCount` from `libplugin.so`*, because the function itself is in `libBadLad.so`. This is already initialised and is pointing to an `int` that has the value of 1.
8. The count is incremented.
9. Meanwhile, `sCount` from `libplugin.so` sits quietly, being initialised to `nullptr`.
10. The library is unloaded and loaded again, etc.

And the moral of the story is? *Static variables are evil*. Avoid.

Note the C++ standard has nothing to say about any of this, as it does not deal with dynamic loading.

However a similar effect can be reproduced without any dynaamic loaading.

```
   // foo.cpp
   #include "badlad.h"

   // bar.cpp
   #include "badlad.h"
   int main () {}
```

Build and test:

```
   # > g++ -o test foo.cpp bar.cpp badlad.cpp
   ./test
   BadLad, reset count to, 1
   BadLad, 2
   BadLad, 3
   ~BadLad, 2
   Segmentation fault
```

Why segmentation fault? This is our good old static initialisation order fiasco. The moral of the story? *Static variables are evil*.

Comment: You are totally right! If I make BadLad constructor inline, sCount will never surpass 1.